# HTML for CSS Tooltip?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I'm trying to make a tooltip on an image with this website: http://csstooltip.com/
I can't seem to get the HTML down for it though, could anyone help me out here? 
Thanks so much guys.

P.S: I did attempt to do it and this is how it came out(I want it on an IMAGE but I tried it on a link just for a test):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lclVM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/yFbLR/1/

This is the html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <span class="tooltip">Welcome!!!</span>
  </div>
```

and this is the css

```
body{
    background-color:grey;
}
span.tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 20px;
      line-height: 20px;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: center;
      color: rgb(113, 157, 171);
      background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      border: 4px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 1px 1px 1px;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 1px 1px 2px 0px;
}

span.tooltip:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-width: 10px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #FFFFFF transparent transparent transparent;
      top: 44px;
      left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: How would I apply that to an image?

Comment: Make the image the background.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not quite sure what you’re trying to do. But if you want the tooltip to appear on any element, simply wrap it in a relatively positioned element (e.g. a `div`- or a `span`-Element). Then you are free to position your tooltip the way you like.

#### Example

View on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/jeyahewu/)!

HTML:

```
<span class="tooltip">
    <img src="//placekitten.com/g/300/200" alt="Sweet Kitten" />
    <span>your text here</span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block; /* add this for use with images */
}
.tooltip > span {
     /* positioning */
     position: absolute;
     width: 150px;
     height: 40px;
     top: -50px;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -75px;

     /* further styling */
     …
}
```